# Error in connecting PHP to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Good day! I'm trying to connect my code to the database localhost/phpmyadmin.

This is my code:

In register.php file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('dbconfig/config.php');
    //phpinfo();
?>
```

config.php is file where the database name was located

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:#bdc3c7">
    <div id="main-wrapper">
    <center><h2>Registration Form</h2></center>
        <form action="register.php" method="post">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <img src="imgs/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="inner_container">
                <label><b>Username</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
                <label><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
                <label><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="cpassword" required>
                <button name="register" class="sign_up_btn" type="submit">Sign Up</button>

                <a href="index.php"><button type="button" class="back_btn"><< Back to Login</button></a>
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['register']))
            {
                @$username=$_POST['username'];
                @$password=$_POST['password'];
                @$cpassword=$_POST['cpassword'];

                if($password==$cpassword)
                {
                    $query = "select * from userinfotbl where username='$username'";
                    //echo $query;
                $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                //echo mysql_num_rows($query_run);
                if($query_run)
                    {
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
                        {
                            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This Username Already exists.. Please try another username!")</script>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $query = "insert into userinfotbl values('$username','$password')";
                            $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                            if($query_run)
                            {
                                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("User Registered.. Welcome")</script>';
                                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                                $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                                header( "Location: homepage.php");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '<p class="bg-danger msg-block">Registration Unsuccessful due to server error. Please try later</p>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("DB error")</script>';
                    }
                }
```

This line where error occurs. But i don't know exactly what happened.

```
                else
                {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Password and Confirm Password do not match")</script>';
                }

            }
            else
            {
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However in localhost page i got an error saying "Localhost says: DB Error"
I don't know what's wron with it.

Comment: where you intiate `$con` variable @Rolly

Comment: `echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This Username Already exists.. Please try another username!")</script>';` that is not a way to show alert box

Comment: Localhost only says DB Error or something else with it? Please show us your configuration file too. Also there are 2 major mistakes in your code i.e. Do not use MySQL, it's deprecated, use MySQLi instead. Second you are passing post variable directly into your query which will lead to SQL injection.

Comment: You need to track the correct error with [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: I am not a PHP expert but, I think the way you are composing and executing your query could easily lead to SQL injection

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru this my code in config.php file (<?php
$con=mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because:' . mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db ($con,'sampleLoginDB');
?>)

Answer (score 0):

It means that the `"select * from userinfotbl where username='$username'"` query do not found any entities which would match a condition or got an error.

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Use [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see what an error you got.

Example:

```
if($password==$cpassword)
{
    $query = "select * from userinfotbl where username='$username'";
    //echo $query;
    $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    //echo mysql_num_rows($query_run);
    if(!empty($query_run)) {
        ...
    } elseif ($query_run === false)
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    else
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("DB error")</script>';
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to run it on the code. The error now says :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\SampleLoginPage\register.php on line 47. When i tried to locate the line 47. I found the code "echo mysqli_error($con);"

Comment: this the file where my codes are attached. Please figure it out what's wrong with my code. please help me. Thanks! https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bypc2WaMNu76Yi1KU0IwN0FPYmM/view?usp=drive_web

Answer (score 0):

you must use [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to check if there is an error in connection or query error